# Activities are not opening in the correct order

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to display a Splash screen and then an Intro for my Android app.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
```

But somewhy when I run it this way the Intro appears to be first to open and then the splash screen.
But without opening the Intro(deleting `startActivity(intent2);`), the splash screen appears to open ok.

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".IntroActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startActivity` is asynchronous call. So no guarantee that activities will be shown in the order you called `startActivity`. To fix, leave only one call:

```
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
```

Then call

```
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
```

from SplashActivity.

Comment: if the layout resources are fixed i think second call i.e his Intro activity will always be upfront..

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh nothing about that in docs. However it's clearly asynchronous if you look at the sources of `ApplicationContext`, for example here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/bcf848e096b600ee36430849ade76826c3062196/core/java/android/app/ApplicationContext.java#545

Comment: it is not documented because most of the time like 99% it works in sequential order though only issue could be that splash layout taking more time for inflation

Comment: @AntonMalyshev The thing is SplashActivity got finish(); at the end of a timer. So basically the code should open SplashActivity, close it, open IntroActivity, close it.

Comment: @DavidKuramshin why can't you open IntroActivity from SplashActivity moving the timer code inside SplashActivity?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev because I want to open IntroActivity only for the first time entering the app. So I need to have a boolean for the first login, saved with shared preferences and by the value of the boolean that boolean opening IntroActivity.(But before that open SplashActivity)

Comment: @DavidKuramshin should be no problem - just check the boolean value and decide which activity to start - IntroActivity or SplashActivity

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Thanks buddy! It tunes out the whole time the problem was with the timer.

Comment: @DavidKuramshin no problem :) please accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can't open both activities. You should open `SplashActivity.class`, then from it open other activity. Or you can create splash screen which shows before starting activity instead of using `SplashActivity.class`.
You just need create style for your splash screen and fill up your manifest.

***`AndroidManifest.xml`*:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".IntroActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
</activity>
```

***`res/values/styles.xml`*:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/mysplash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now before your `IntroActivity.class` splash screen will be shown and no `SplashActivity.class` is needed anymore.

Comment: The thing is SplashActivity has an animation and got finish(); at the end of a timer. So basically the code should open SplashActivity, close it, open IntroActivity(that also has finish();), close it.

Comment: @DavidKuramshin You should start `SplashActivity` from it before `finish()` start `IntroActivity` then from it before `finish()` start next activity. This is how it goes. From first open second, from second the third and go on...

Answer (score 0):

Calling two activities simultaneously won't guarantee which one will be called first. 
So
In onCreate of MainActivity, you will have to call SplashScreenActivity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Do something

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In onCreate of SplashScreenActivity, you will have to call IntroActivity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Do something

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```